# In Android, how to get the profile of a connected bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Following a lot of answers here, I am able to build the list of connected bluetooth devices with the help of a `BroadcastReceiver`. Now my question is how do I know which device supports which profile. I want to be able to pick the devices based on the profile, for example, get a list of currently connected devices and their profile, and pick one of them. I don't see how I can get such info if I have the instance of BluetoothDevice.

On this page there are some codes illustrating how to work with a bluetooth headset profile: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Profiles. But it doesn't solve my problem. If you think I am missing anything, please help me and point it out.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same problem. It doesn't appear that you can get the available profiles from the **BluetoothDevice** class.
But there is a long way around by getting a **List** of **BluetoothDevice**s from the **getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates** method in the **BluetoothProfile** class.

For example if you want to find which **BluetoothDevice**s support A2DP, first create a custom **BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener**

```
public class cServiceListener implements BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener {
private static final int[] states={ BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTING,
                                    BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED,
                                    BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED,
                                    BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING};
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile bluetoothProfile) {
List<BluetoothDevice> Devices=bluetoothProfile.getDevicesMatchingConnectionStates(states);
    for (BluetoothDevice loop:Devices){
        Log.i("myTag",loop.getName());
    }
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
}

}
```

Then attach it to the profile you want to check, in this example A2DP

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
cServiceListener mServiceListener=new cServiceListener();
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(thisContext,mServiceListener, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
```

This will logcat *all* the bluetooth devices that support A2DP which are in the requested ***states***. In this example it includes all devices which are currently connected and previously paired devices which are disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Android source code, you can guess which profiles are available for a device by looking at its UUIDs, and then connect each profile one by one.

**Step 0 :** Copy the `_PROFILE_UUIDS` constants from there : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/9ad703cdb9a8d0972c123b041d18aa7bbeb391a4/src/com/android/settings/bluetooth/LocalBluetoothProfileManager.java

**Step 1 :** get your `BluetoothDevice`, via scanning for instance. Assure that it's properly bonded.

**Step 2 :** register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the `android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_UUID` action intent

**Step 3 :** on your device, call the `fetchUuidsWithSdp` method

**Step 4** : you will recieve a `ACTION_UUID` broadcast : in the `onReceive` method you can unregister the receiver, and get the list of profiles like so :

```
ArrayList<Integer> profiles = new ArrayList<>();

ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();

if (BluetoothUuid.containsAnyUuid(uuids, HEADSET_PROFILE_UUIDS))
{
    profiles.add(BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);
}

if (BluetoothUuid.containsAnyUuid(uuids, A2DP_PROFILE_UUIDS))
{
    profiles.add(BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
}

if (BluetoothUuid.containsAnyUuid(uuids, OPP_PROFILE_UUIDS))
{
    //OPP doesn't have any BluetoothProfile value
}

if (BluetoothUuid.containsAnyUuid(uuids, HID_PROFILE_UUIDS))
{
    //You will need system privileges in order to use this one
    profiles.add(BluetoothProfile.INPUT_DEVICE);
}

if (BluetoothUuid.containsAnyUuid(uuids, PANU_PROFILE_UUIDS))
{
    profiles.add(BluetoothProfile.PAN);
}
```

**Step 5 :** get the proxies for the profiles, one by one :

```
for (int profile : profiles)
{
    if (!adapter.getProfileProxy(context, listener, profile))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

**Step 6 :** do anything with each proxy retrieved in the `onServiceConnected` method of your listener. You can access the `connect` method using relfection.