# Grouping multiple Bluetooth devices

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an Android app that manages multiple Bluetooth LE devices such as speakers, lighting devices, various sensors.

For user convenience, these devices have to be 'grouped' together and only accessible through a single Bluetooth connection.

Is programming some kind of custom intermediary hardware to serve as an interface required in this case or are there some better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to group bluetooth device by the *profiles* they implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles . In Android the profile of a bluetooth device can possibly be determined like in [In Android, how to get the profile of a connected bluetooth device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556797/in-android-how-to-get-the-profile-of-a-connected-bluetooth-device)